# SQL Server 2012 Count

Tags: sql-server, count

I'm using SQL Server 2012. I have a table `CustomerMaster`. Here is some sample content:

```
+--------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
| CustNo | NewMainCustNo | Longname        | NoOfMembers |
+--------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
| 3653   | 3653          | GroupId:003     |             |
| 3654   | 3654          | GroupId:004     |             |
| 11     | 3653          | Peter Evans     |             |
| 155    | 3653          | Harold Charley  |             |
| 156    | 3654          | David Arnold    |             |
| 160    | 3653          | Mickey Willson  |             |
| 2861   | 3653          | Jonathan Wickey |             |
| 2871   | 3653          | William Jason   |             |
+--------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

The `NewMainCustNo` for Customer records is equivalent to `CustNo` from Group records. Basically each customer belongs to a particular group.

My question is how to update the `NoOfMembers` column for group records with total number of customer belongs to a certain group.

Please share your ideas on how to do this.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with

```
update CustomerMaster 
set NoOfMembers = (select count(*) from CustomerMaster m2 where m2.NewMainCustNo = CustomerMaster.CustNo and m2.CustNo <> CustomerMaster.CustNo) 
where LongName like 'GroupId:%'
```

Check [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5afb1/2) to see the query in action.

However I disagree with your data structure. You should have a separate table for your groups. In your customer table you only need to reference the ID of the group in the group table. This makes everything (including the query above) much cleaner.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, but it's a lot more easier having all in one table for data migration purpose. These are not live DB contents. These are data required for DM purpose. Thank you all for the support.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a window function for the update.  Here is an example with an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select cm.*, count(*) over (partition by NewMainCustNo) as grpcount
      from customermaster
     )
update toupdate
    set NoOfMembers = grpcount;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but it also calculates the Group record. What I want is number of members belongs to a group excluding the group record. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Devinda . . . Can you just subtract 1?

Comment: Hi Gordon, no I didn't try subtracting by 1, I will try and let you know man. many thanx for your support, cheers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the option to do so, but I would separate groups out into their own table.

```
create table Groups (
        GroupID int primary key,
        Name varchar(200)
    )
```

Then, change NewMainCustNo to GroupID, create, purge your customer table of groups, and go from there.  Then, getting a group count would be:

```
select  GroupID, 
        Name [Group Name],
        COUNT(*)
    from Groups g
    join Customers c on
        c.GroupID = g.GroupID
```